# Cannot upload new build file XCode 6.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have XCode 6.3.2. I have build\t a swift project, compiled it and archived it. I cannot seem to validate it because when I run validate it just hangs/spins forever. When I try to upload app to the app store, it crashes. I thought it might have something to do with the fact that I have a new iPhone 6, so I regenerated all my provisioning profiles. I then manually selected these profiles in my XCode profject and tried again. This time it didn't crash but gave me an error that the upload failed because I am not authorized to perform that operation. I believe this is because my apple ID on itunes connect (where I am authorized) is different from my apple ID I use for the IOS developer program. So I tried exporting the build to an IPA file. Howevere, if I use Application Loader, this IPA file is grayed out regardless of which apple ID I choose.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Ususally the developer program ID and itunes connect ID must be the same for you to upload

Comment: Your app ID should contain the right bundle identifier and your provisioning profile should have the right App ID selected. Please cross check these.

Answer (score 2):

i have this issue too. And this is how I solved it.

Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Select Archive -> Export -> Save for iOS App Store Deployment

To Upload:
Open 'Application Loader' and follow the steps

Notes:
-Apple Developer Program ID must be the same as the iTunes Connect account ID
-In Xcode, use the iTunes connect ID to login and upload app

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The IPA file is grayed out regardless of which account I sign in with in Application Loader. Any other ideas?

Comment: were you able to to upload before?

Comment: Ususally the developer program ID and itunes connect ID must be the same for you to upload....i got the "Not authorized" error before too...in your apple developer, try invite the itunes connect ID as a developer